# React Apollo - Child not updating based on result change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo

I am using React Apollo to work with a GaphQL backend. The function I am creating allows users to edit the admin permissions of another user.

I have two components. One component contains the React Apollo logic, including the query and the mutation components. When this component is rendered a prop that is passed down from a match parameter in the router specifies what admin to get the permissions of which is used in the GraphQL query. When the data required for the admin permissions component is retrieved it is passed as a prop to the child component which sets the initial state based on the prop. The child component contains no React Apollo logic and simply contains checkboxes and other inputs that update the state of the component as they are changed. When clicking the save changes button the parent's mutation function is called passing the newly updated permissions to insert variables into the mutation query.

The issue that I am facing is that sometimes the state does not change depending on the props. For example, admin 1 is accessed, the router then updates the URL when a button is clicked to access admin 2. It works up to this point. The router then updates the URL again when a button is clicked to access admin 1, admin 2 is still shown in the child component, despite the props being updated with the new values. Note the constructor of the child component is not called again.

Any suggestions on how I can ensure that when the data produced by the GraphQL query displays the correct child componenet instance? Furthermore, any suggestions on how the structure of this componenet can be improved.

```
render(){
if(this.props.steamID ===  null) return null;

const QUERY_VARIABLES = {
  serverID: this.props.serverID,
  selectedAdminSteamID: this.props.steamID,
  currentAdminSteamID: Auth.claim.steamID
};

return (
  <Query
    query={QUERY}
    variables={QUERY_VARIABLES}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return ( ... );
      if (error) return ( ... );
      if(!data.server.selectedAdmin) return ( ... );

      return (
        <Mutation
          mutation={MUTATION}
          update={(cache, { data: { updateAdminPermission } }) => {
            const data = cache.readQuery({ query: QUERY, variables: QUERY_VARIABLES });
            data.server.selectedAdmin = updateAdminPermission;
            cache.writeQuery({ query: QUERY, variables: QUERY_VARIABLES, data: data, });
          }}
        >

          {(updateAdminPermission, { loading, error }) => (
            <>
              <AdminPermissions
                serverID={this.props.serverID}
                steamID={this.props.steamID}

                selectedAdmin={data.server.selectedAdmin}
                currentAdmin={data.server.currentAdmin}

                updatePermissionFunction={(variables) => {
                  updateAdminPermission({ variables })
                }}
                updatePermissionLoading={loading}
              />
              <GraphQLErrorModal error={error} />
            </>
          )}

        </Mutation>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);
}

class AdminPermissions extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super();

      this.state = props.selectedAdmin;

      this.guid = React.createRef();
      this.updatePermission = this.updatePermission.bind(this);
      this.saveChanges = this.saveChanges.bind(this);
    }

    updatePermission(changedPermission, value){
      if(changedPermission === 'manageAssignPermissions' && value > 0){
        for(let permission of panelPermissions.concat(gamePermissions)){
          if(permission.permission === 'manageAssignPermissions') continue;
          this.setState({ [permission.permission]: 2 });
        }
      }
      this.setState({ [changedPermission]: value });
    }

    saveChanges(){
      this.props.updatePermissionFunction({
        serverID: this.props.serverID,
        steamID: this.props.steamID,
        guid: this.guid.current.value,
        ...this.state
      });
    }

    render(){
        // renders pairs of checkboxes with checked value based on state and on change event that calls update permissions method passing the name of the associated permission and a value that is calculated based on which boxes in the pair are ticked.
    }
 }
```

**Query (Update)**

```
  query AdminPermission($serverID: Int!, $selectedAdminSteamID: String!, $currentAdminSteamID: String!) {
    server(id: $serverID) {
      id

      selectedAdmin: adminPermission(steamID: $selectedAdminSteamID) {    
        _id

        admin {
          _id

          steamID
          displayName
          avatar
        }

        player {
          _id
          guid
        }

        manageAssignPermissions
        viewAdminPermissions
        ...
      }
      currentAdmin: adminPermission(steamID: $currentAdminSteamID) {
        _id

        admin {
          _id
          steamID
        }

        manageAssignPermissions
        viewAdminPermissions
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the actual query you're sending?

Comment: The query's content isn't really relevant, but it basically fetches a set of properties that are either 0, 1 or 2 and some additional properties about the admin, like their display name, avatar, etc.

Comment: Try to add `fetchPolicy='cache-and-network'` to your `<Query>`

Comment: @ThomasSmyth The query's content can be relevant if it's causing your query not to being cached correctly. Most of the time, these sort of issues are due to Apollo's cache normalization.

Comment: @DanielRearden I do apologise, I do not realise this problem was as a result of the caching.

Comment: @Fraction that did work, but I am confused as to why it worked. The correct data was always returned from the query, so how come it did not select the correct component?

Comment: @ThomasSmyth see my answer :)

Comment: @ThomasSmyth No need to apologize, but you could update your question to include the query

Answer (score 1):

You must set the `Query`'s `fetchPolicy` to `cache-and-network`, by default it's `cache-first`:

```
<Query
    query={QUERY}
    variables={QUERY_VARIABLES}
    fetchPolicy='cache-and-network'
  >
```

If you read the  [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy):

> - **cache-first**: This is the default value where we always try reading
>     data from your cache first. If all the data needed to fulfill your
>     query is in the cache then that data will be returned. Apollo will
>     only fetch from the network if a cached result is not available. This
>     fetch policy aims to minimize the number of network requests sent when
>     rendering your component.
> - **cache-and-network**: This fetch policy will
>     have Apollo first trying to read data from your cache. If all the data
>     needed to fulfill your query is in the cache then that data will be
>     returned. However, regardless of whether or not the full data is in
>     your cache this fetchPolicy will always execute query with the network
>     interface unlike cache-first which will only execute your query if the
>     query data is not in your cache. This fetch policy optimizes for users
>     getting a quick response while also trying to keep cached data
>     consistent with your server data at the cost of extra network
>     requests.

Comment: Changing the variables for a query should initially result in a cache miss, even if the policy is `cache-first`. If the wrong data is being returned from the cache it's normally because `dataIdFromObject` was incorrectly implemented or there's a missing `id` field. While this may fix the problem, it also means that any time the component rerenders, a request will be made to the server, which may not be desirable.

Comment: @DanielRearden for caching to be done is it common practice to return the id field of the object in the database in the results data? If so I assume this needs to be included within the typedef on the server and explicitly requested by the query? Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Yes every object should return an id or _id field because Apollo uses it to generate the cache key. If one is not available you can use dataIdFromObject. See [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching#normalization).

Comment: @ThomasSmyth yes, it is important to include the id in the result of the queries and mutations to let apollo update the cache automatically [more info](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates#automatic-updates)

Comment: and you need `cache.writeQuery` only when you add a new item, in the case of update and if you include the id in the mutation's result the cache will be updated automatically

Comment: @DanielRearden I've added `_id` as a field for all typedefs that returns the mongoose object id string and I've added it to the graphql query, however, it does not resolve the issue when removing the `fetchPolicy` specified above. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ThomasSmyth you've added it also to the mutations queries ? take a look at the link I've posted in the comment above

Comment: @Fraction aye, I added it to the mutation too but ignoring that for now, simply querying with the id fields in the results does not seem to cache as it should.